# Faster alternative to for loop in R which calls a function with another loop

Tags: r, performance, parsing, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to parse a huge dataset into R (1.3Gb). The original data is a list comprised of four million of characters, being each one of them an observation of 137 variables.

First I've created a function that separates the character according to the key provided in the dataset, where "d" is each one of the characters. For the purpose of this question imagine that d has this form

"2005400d"

and the key would be

```
varName <- c("YEAR","AGE","GENDER","STATUS")
varIn   <- c(1,5,7,8)
varEND  <- c(4,6,7,8)
```

where varIn and varEnd track the splitting points. The function created was.

```
parseLine<-function(d){
  k<-unlist(strsplit(d,""))
  vec<-rep(NA,length(varName))
  for (i in 1:length(varName)){
    vec[i]<-paste(k[varIn[i]:varEnd[i]],sep="",collapse="")
  }
  return(vec)
}
```

And then in order to loop over all the data available, I've created a for loop.

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(varName)))
names(df)<-as.character(varName)

for (i in 1:length(data)){
  df<-rbind(df,parseLine(data[i]))
}
```

However when I check the function with 1,000 iterations I got a system time of 10.82 seconds, but when I increase that to 10,000 instead of having a time of 108.2 seconds I've got a time of 614.77 which indicates that as the number of iterations increases the time needed would increase exponentially.

**Any suggestion for speeding up the process?** I've tried to use the library foreach, but it didn't use the parallel as I expected.

```
m<-foreach(i=1:10,.combine=rbind) %dopar% parseLine(data[i])
df<-a
names(df)<-as.character(varName)
```

Comment: In your first loop, are you -just- doing `substring("2005400d", varIn, varEND)`? If not, it seems that you could use something similar to that (which is faster, too)

Comment: Is your original data formatted with fixed width? Then [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720036/reading-big-data-with-fixed-width) may be relevant.

Comment: don't keep `rbind`ing to the data frame; create a list of individual data frames, then `do.call(rbind,ListOfDataFrames)`

Answer (score 3):

Why re-invent the wheel? Use read.fwf in the utils package (attached by default)

```
> dat <- "2005400d"
> varName <- c("YEAR","AGE","GENDER","STATUS")
> varIn   <- c(1,5,7,8)
> varEND  <- c(4,6,7,8)
> read.fwf(textConnection(dat), col.names=varName, widths=1+varEND-varIn)
  YEAR AGE GENDER STATUS
1 2005  40      0      d
```

You should get further efficiency if you specify colClasses but my effort to demonstrate this failed to show a difference. Perhaps that advice only applies to `read.table` and cousins.

Comment: I am so stupid... thank you very much I did not know about read.fwf function... really thanks!!