# R: how to read a whitespace-separated table where some string fields also contain spaces

Tags: r, fixed-width, read.table

I have some trouble importing a text file seperated by space / multiple spaces that also contains columns with strings that have spaces that should not be interpreted as seperators!

The table has no column names and a maximum of 9 columns. Column 6 is cmoprised by a string with spaces in it. Columns 4, 7, 8, 9 are optional and partly missing.

My idea was to use the fixed column widths when reading the table but was technically not able to achieve this..

Here is the file-url: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt

Because read.table throws an error,

```
> read.table("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt",sep="")
Fehler in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  Zeile 1 hatte keine 9 Elemente
```

I did this instead

```
lines <- readLines("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt")
```

Here's a sample of `lines`:

```
a <- c("USC00080211  29.7258  -85.0206    6.1 FL APALACHICOLA  AIRPORT              HCN 72220", 
"USC00080228  27.2181  -81.8739    9.1 FL ARCADIA                            HCN      ", 
"USC00080236  27.1819  -81.3508   42.7 FL ARCHBOLD BIO STN                            ", 
"USC00080369  27.5947  -81.5267   46.9 FL AVON PARK 2 W                               ", 
"USC00080374  27.6000  -81.5000   46.0 FL AVON PARK 1 NW                              ", 
"USC00080390  27.8500  -81.5167   38.1 FL BABSON PARK 1 ENE                           ", 
"USC00080414  24.6589  -81.2761    0.9 FL BAHIA HONDA SP                              ", 
"USC00080478  27.8986  -81.8433   38.1 FL BARTOW                             HCN      ", 
"ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD                       ", 
"ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST JOHNS                                    ", 
"AE000041196  25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP            GSN     41196"
)
tf <- tempfile(fileext=".txt")
writeLines(a,tf)
shell.exec(tf)

#read.table(tf, sep = "", ??)
```

Comment: I think the trick is to consider it as fixed width file. Following question with answers should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720036/reading-big-data-with-fixed-width

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 1):

**For the record:**

Here's the solution I found thanks to @bdecaf..

```
lines <- readLines("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt")

w <- list(c(1,12), c(13,22), c(23,31), c(32,38), c(39,41), c(42,72), c(73,76), c(77,80), c(81,87))
ns <- c()
for(i in 1:length(w)) {
     ns[i] <- paste("C", i, sep = ".")
     assign(ns[i], str_trim(substring(lines, w[[i]][1], w[[i]][2])))
}

obj.list <- lapply(ns, get)
names(obj.list) <- ns
df <- data.frame(obj.list)
```

Comment: Yep, that's the best way.  For reference, there is a function `write.fwf` that will let you write data back to a fixed-width format if that becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered an issue that matches the title of this post.  Albeit my problem was much simpler than the one in the body of the original post.  I could not find a solution to my issue anywhere. Given how much trouble this issue caused me I thought I would go ahead and post my solution here in the hope it might be helpful to others.

```
my.data1  = read.csv(text = '
1,10,40,30,X_    ,
2,80,90,20,Y_,
3,30,40,50,Z_  ,
', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data1 <- my.data1[,1:(ncol(my.data1)-1)]

my.data2  = read.table(text = '
     1  10 40 30 \'X_    \'
     2  80 90 20 \'Y_\'
     3  30 40 50 \'Z_  \'
', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="")
my.data2
#  V1 V2 V3 V4     V5
#1  1 10 40 30 X_    
#2  2 80 90 20     Y_
#3  3 30 40 50   Z_  

all.equal(my.data1, my.data2)
#[1] TRUE
```